# How do i verifying User password from mysql DB

Tags: php, mysql, hash, verifyerror

I have a problem by verifying a user password from my mySQL DB.
At first i hash my Password and write it to my DB:

First my register Handler:

```
class RegisterHandler
{
    /**
     * @var RegisterQuery
     * 
     */
    private $register;

    /**
     * @var HashPassword
     *
     */
    private $HashPassword;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     */
    private $getUsername;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     */
    private $username;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->username = $_POST['username'];
        $this->register = new RegisterQuery;
        $this->checkUsername = new SelectUsernameQuery;
        $this->HashPassword = new HashPassword($_POST['password']);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $hashedPassword = $this->HashPassword->getHashedPassword();
        $salt = $this->HashPassword->getSalt();

        $dbUser = $this->checkUsername->execute($this->username);
        $dbUser->bindValue( 1, $this->username);
        $dbUser->execute();

        if( !$dbUser->rowCount() == 0 ) { # If rows are found for query
            echo "Username found";
            return;
        }

        $this->register->execute($this->username, $hashedPassword, $salt, $_POST['name']);

    }
}
```

You can see i hash my password in the execute function with this code: (forget salt i dont use it anymore)

```
class HashPassword
{
    /**
     * @var string
     * 
     */
    private $salt = 'x';

    /**
     * @var string
     * 
     */
    private $hashedPassword;

    public function __construct($password)
    {
        $this->hashedPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => 12]);
        $this->getHashedPassword();
    }

    public function getHashedPassword()
    {
        return $this->hashedPassword;
    }
}
```

after hashing the password i write the hash into de DB.

And now is my question:
How do i get the password from DB to verify it?

i tried it:

```
class LoginHandler
{

    private $databaseWrapper;

    /**
     * @var SelectUsernameQuery
     * 
     */
    private $checkUsername;

    private $checkPassword;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     */
    private $enteredUsername;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     */
    private $enteredPassword;

    /**
     * @var HashPassword
     *
     */
    private $passwordHasher;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->databaseWrapper = new DatabaseWrapper;
        $this->checkUsername = new SelectUsernameQuery;
        $this->checkPassword = new SelectPasswordQuery;
        $this->enteredUsername = $_POST['username'];

        $this->passwordHasher = new HashPassword($this->enteredPassword);
    }

    private function createSessionName()
    {
        $_SESSION['name'] = $this->enteredUsername;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $this->verifyUser();
    }

    private function verifyUser()
    {
        $this->enteredPassword = $_POST['password'];
        $userDBHash = $this->checkPassword->execute($this->enteredUsername);
        $userDBHash->execute();
        if(password_verify($this->enteredPassword, $userDBHash))
        {
            echo 'password is valid';
        }

        $dbUsername = $this->checkUsername->execute($this->enteredUsername);
        $dbUsername->bindValue( 1, $this->enteredUsername);
        $dbUsername->execute();

        if( !$dbUsername->rowCount() == 0 ) { # If rows are found for query
            echo 'Username: '."$this->enteredUsername".' was found!';
            $this->createSessionName();
            return;
        }

        echo 'Ups, This Username: '."$this->enteredUsername".' was not found!';    }
    }
}
```

In the verifyUser class i write the enteredpassword in a variable
After that i get the hash from DB in $userDBHash with this query:

```
private function getUsername($username)
{
    return $this->databaseWrapper->getPDO()->prepare(
           "SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
}
```

After that I try to `password_verify($this->enteredPassword, $userDBHash)`
but i get the following error:

```
Warning: password_verify() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in /var/www/c2b/src/Handlers/LoginHandler.php on line 72
```

Comment: So, what does `$this->enteredPassword` and `$userDBHash` contain? One of them is not a string but something else.

Comment: $enteredPassword contains the password of the which gets called by $_POST and $userDBHash contains the the hash of the password in the database. So its an array right ? How can i convert it ?

Comment: I don't know what `$userDBHash` contains since the code that sets it is not visible, however, the error message quite clearly states that it is not a string but and object. From your code, I would assume that it might be a PDOStatement: `$userDBHash->execute();`

Comment: As @1615903 wrote, the variable `$userDBHash` must contain the hash stored in he database. According to the error message it does not contain a string.

Comment: As i wrote in the question:

In the verifyUser class i write the enteredpassword in a variable After that i get the hash from DB in **$userDBHash with this 

`private function getUsername($username)
{
    return $this->databaseWrapper->getPDO()->prepare(
           "SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
}`

Comment: That function does not return the hash, it returns a PDOStatement.

Comment: The function is also not called from anywhere in your code that you have posted. Furthermore, it's name is confusing - `getUsername`, but presumably it is supposed to return the hashed password for a specific user?

Comment: How would you getUsernsme call ?    Yes it should return the hash of a specific user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem seems to be, how to get the password hash from the database. I made a quick example out of my head (not tested), but it should get you started.

```
private function getPasswordHashFromDatabase($username)
{
  $pdo = $this->databaseWrapper->getPDO();
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = ?');
  $stmt->bindParam(1, $username);
  if ($stmt->execute())
  {
    if ($row = $stmt->fetch())
    {
      return $row[0];
    }
  }
  return '';
}
```

Note the `?` in the select statement, using prepared statements protects your application from SQL-injection.

Comment: ** Edit

It works very well ! First i failed.. I never did a $_POST for the password.. now it works :) Thank you very much !